# My Meteor app cannot make ajax call to my webapi if it is running on ios iphone, but can call ajax to my webapi running as meteor app

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ajax, asp.net-web-api

My Meteor app cannot make ajax call to my .Net WebAPI if it is running on ios iphone, but can call ajax to my webapi running as meteor app.
I compiled my meteor app with XCode 8.0 and Meteor 1.4.1 and target is iOS 10 for iPhone 6 Plus.

can someone help me with this issue?

Below is my code snipped:
All codes are running within the controller.js without calling meter server codes.
the mmResults arrow is a reactive variables which is being binded to the UI controls in the html file which is not important in this question. I am hoping to know why this piece of codes able to call the webapi successfully, but failed if running within the iOS 10 iPhone 6. Thank you in advanced.

Also the UserToken is currently being ignored so it is okay to pass UserToken as empty string.

Also the startDate and endDate are being overwritten with specific date.

$scope.MMResults = function (startDate, endDate) {
        //alert('in MMResults()');

```
    var username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    var password = 'mypassword';
    var state = 'ca';
    var game = 'mm';
    var gameType = 'mm';
    var numberType = 'mega';

    url = 'http://pAPI.mydomain.Com:81/Api/GlgResults';

    //alert('in ajax call now');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            Username: 'myemail@gmail.com',
            UserToken: '',
            State: state,
            Game: game,
            GameType: gameType,
            NumberType: numberType,
            StartDate: '2016-01-01', //startDate,
            EndDate: '2016-12-30', //endDate,
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //debugger
            //alert('in ajax call success');
            $scope.MMAjaxToMMResultsSuccess(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            //alert('in ajax call failed!');
            alert(xhr);
            alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}

$scope.MMAjaxToMMResultsSuccess = function (data) {
    //alert('in MMAjaxToMMResultsSuccess()');
    //alert('in PBAjaxToPBResultsSuccess');
    //alert(data);

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

    var length = Object.keys(jsonData).length;

    if (length > 10) length = 10;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var item = jsonData[i];
        var drawndate = item.Draw_Date.substring(0, 4) + "-" + item.Draw_Date.substring(5, 7) + '-' + item.Draw_Date.substring(8, 10);

            $scope.mmResults[i].date = drawndate;
            $scope.mmResults[i].col1 = item.Number_1;
            $scope.mmResults[i].col2 = item.Number_2;
            $scope.mmResults[i].col3 = item.Number_3;
            $scope.mmResults[i].col4 = item.Number_4;
            $scope.mmResults[i].col5 = item.Number_5;
            $scope.mmResults[i].col6 = item.Number_0;

    }
```